# Undefined or a boolean?

Tags: javascript, boolean, undefined

I have a piece of code that looks somewhat like this (in JavaScript):

```
var panelAvailible = false;
// When an specifc event occurs:
panelAvailible = true;
// Later in the code...
if (panelAvailible) {
...
}
```

I have another option availible in order to get the same effect, but it uses `undefined` in a strange way.

```
// When an specifc event occurs:
var panelAvailible;
// Later in the code...
if (panelAvailible !== undefined) {
...
}
```

My idea when writing it using undefined is that I don't need to define another variable until/unless necessary, and the code is shorter.

1. Would this code be considered an ugly hack, or is it okay to use in everyday programming?
2. Which variation would be interpreted faster?

Comment: You don't declare variable twice - use `var` once for the first declaration. "Which variation would be interpreted faster?" --- it doesn't matter

Comment: I don't think speed is an issue here. The second code block you posted is fine. In the first code block however, you don't need to specify "var" again after you have already defined it once.

Comment: I don't see the distinction between the two examples. Or in the first one is `panelAvailable` a flag for the existence of a separate variable?

Comment: So how the value of `panelAvailible` is changed in the second piece of code? Why did you omit it?

Comment: @zerkms They do the same thing, and the idea is which one to use.

Comment: @user2510822: they are identical aren't they? I don't see the difference - could you point to one?

Comment: Since it is a boolean, I would personally prefer using the first option, since then `panelAvailible` would have a meaning every step of  the way instead of just being `true` or `undefined`.

Comment: So looking at your update, your question is whether to initialize with `false` or to leave it uninitialized. From the way you're using it, it really just doesn't matter at all. It's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Oh, and now you removed the update. So we don't know what happens to the variable, so we can't know the actual situation. Impossible to give an answer WRT correctness.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yea, that was what I asking. I think you're right about the personal preference thing.

Comment: @user2510822: why did you remove my change? Now 2 pieces of code are incomparable. It's not possible to compare an orange and an apple.

Comment: @cookiemonster The variable is never touched otherwise.

Comment: The first option seems more user friendly to me

Comment: If the variable is never touched, then why do you need an `if()` statement? It really makes the two examples seem unrelated.

Comment: @cookiemonster I need an action done if a specific event has occurred. I added the variable to signify when to use a set of code

Comment: @zerkms At this point in time, they accomplish the same thing

Comment: @user2510822: so why do you have `panelAvailible = true;` in first code not in second? When you put it there they become identical. Thus - it's not clear what actually you're asking about.

Comment: @zerkms I should have been more clear. The code inside the `if` statement does not affect the variable, and the variable will not be used again.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm just lost. But if you're asking about simple truthy/falsey evaluation, then yeah it'll just be a matter of opinion. I like explicit initialization to `false`, and sometimes even explicit comparison, but then I also like static type systems while others don't.

Comment: @user2510822: I didn't ask about code inside `if`. I'm asking about line that modifies the flag. Why it is in the first piece of code, and why there is no one in the second? When you put one there - the code samples become identical (with minor differences that change nothing)

Comment: @cookiemonster I think you get it now. You're probably right, being explicit would make it clear and easy to read.

Comment: @zerkms The variable is not used for any other purpose. What the variable ends at is not important. The part that I care about is whether the code in the `if` will run.

Comment: @user2510822: 2 pieces of your code are identical. Probably you didn't take hoisting into account. `var varname` will be hoisted to the beginning of the current scope. So the variable will be declared as `undefined` in **ANY** place of the scope (including any nested scopes), not only after the explicit declaration line.

Comment: @zerkms They are supposed to be identical. I knew they both worked. Reread my questions. I have an answer (not going to use it, too unclear), but I knew both worked.

Comment: I don't know how to close the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you like formal solutions. So here are the formal answers for your questions:

> Would this code be considered an ugly hack, or is it okay to use in everyday programming?

None of them is hack - you're using well defined programming language behaviour.

> Which variation would be interpreted faster?

It doesn't matter.